# Files disappeared after unclean shutdown

Tags: data-recovery

I was installing notepad++ on my Ubuntu 16. After the installation process I clicked on the app and it showed me a black screen and didn't do anything at all, so I pressed and held the power button of my PC and restarted it.

Now all the folders in my directory lost all their files and I don't know how because I didn't run any command like `rm`.

What should I do?

Comment: open up a terminal  ctrl-alt-t   ...  issue  pwd  ... are you in your home directory ?   should be, tell us otherwise  ... issue  ls -la   are your folders there ?

Comment: just tried that, it said command not found

Comment: Your main screen is GUI or CLI? Does it ask for auth? Can you do it?

Comment: here is an alternative way to reach a command prompt ... read and understand ALL of below before issuing anything otherwise you will not be able to return to this screen without rebooting  ... issue this  ctrl-alt-F2  to goto the console ...  do a dir listing ... ls -la  ... are your folders there ?   ... to return to normal screen issue  ctrl-alt-F7